# Xamarin Studio Template Distribution

Tags: templates, xamarin, add-in, xamarin-studio

I'd like to create Xamarin Studio Forms template and distribute it using Xamarin channels. Is there a way that I can distribute add-in package similar to Xamarin Components Store (https://components.xamarin.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can distribute you addin via [monodevelopaddins](http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/publishing-an-addin/)

[Here](https://github.com/matthewrdev/building-addins-for-xamarin-studio) you have a full example from creating to publishing a Xamarin Studio addin.